# SQL Returns new column for selected value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query that returns a new column when a column contains Mike,  it returns 1; when a column doesn't contain Mike, it returns 0. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Before:

| first_name | last_name | name_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Bogo | Johnson |
| David | Mike | Campap |
| Mike | Henderson | Bogart |
| Mike | Jart | Denver |
| Stephen | Dallas | Payne |

After query it should show

| first_name | last_name | name_name | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Bogo | Johnson | 1 |
| David | Mike | Campap | 1 |
| Niall | Henderson | Bogart | 0 |
| Mike | Jart | Denver | 1 |
| Stephen | Dallas | Payne | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using a CASE expression

```
select first_name, last_name, name_name, 
       case 
         when 'Mike' in (first_name, last_name) then 1
         else 0
       end as new_column
from the_table;
```

I would prefer a proper boolean column (with true/false) though:

```
select first_name, last_name, name_name, 
       'Mike' in (first_name, last_name) as new_column
from the_table;
```